# Location of hashed password for Notes app in macOS or iOS

Tags: macos, ios, password, notes.app

I've got a Notes.app note on my phone (iOS) and desktop (macOS 10.14.6) and have forgotten the password. Unable to find where the hashed password is stored so I can attempt to crack it. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove to us remotely that the phone and desktop are actually yours and that you're not trying to crack into somebody else's equipment?

Comment: @IconDaemon I hope I haven't contributed to anything bad by answering it

Comment: I never attempt to answer a question which seeks to crack/hack passwords which are not known to the hacker, even if they claim it is their own device. From where I sit, I cannot tell if chipotle_warrior is a bad actor or just has a bad memory.

Answer (score 1):

Notes' notes' password can be reset using iCloud password in Notes Preferences. Rest is Keychain.

[image]

It can be done on iOS in Settings → Notes → Password.

[image]